# JSON com valor - Lista do App Nulo

Tags: php, java, android, json, android-studio

Estou criando um App, onde ele apresentará algumas informações de um banco de dados externo utilizando um arquivo JSON para que eu consiga apresentar essas informações no App.
Porem quando eu executo o código, a lista em meu app retorna nula e sem nenhum resultado. Gostaria de saber onde estou falhando na construção de meu Código.

```
public class PontosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = PontosActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ListView lstPontos;

private static String url = "http://mpeprojeto.com/pontos";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pontosList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pontos);


    pontosList = new ArrayList<>();

    lstPontos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPontos);

    new GetPontos().execute();


}

private class GetPontos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeHttpHandler(url);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray pontos = jsonObj.getJSONArray("pontos");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < pontos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = pontos.getJSONObject(i);

                    String data = c.getString("datar");
                    String hora = c.getString("horar");
                    String lat = c.getString("latr");
                    String longt = c.getString("longtr");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> ponto = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    ponto.put("datar", data);
                    ponto.put("horar", hora);
                    ponto.put("latr", lat);
                    ponto.put("longtr", longt);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    pontosList.add(ponto);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error1: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error2: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Avalie novamente seus ultimos pontos, pois não foi encontrado nenhum!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if(result!=null) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    PontosActivity.this, pontosList,
                    R.layout.activity_listpontos, new String[]{"Data:", "Hora:",
                    "Latitude:", "Longitude:"}, new int[]{R.id.dataPonto,
                    R.id.horaPonto, R.id.latitudePonto, R.id.longitudePonto});
            adapter.notifyAll();
            lstPontos.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhum Ponto Registrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


}
```

Arquivo JSON:

```
{
"pontos": [
    {
            "datar": "14/11/2016",
            "horar": "20:37:001",
            "latr": "-22.778899",
            "longtr": "-47.554477"
    },
    {

        "datar": "14/11/2016",
            "horar": "20:39:001",
            "latr": "-22.748596",
            "longtr": "-47.858532"

     }
    ]
    }
```

HttpHandler:

```
public class HttpHandler {

private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

public String makeHttpHandler(String reqUrl){
    String resposta = null;

    try{
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        resposta = convertStreamToString(is);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resposta;
}
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dataPonto"
    android:layout_width="67dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/horaPonto"
    android:layout_width="67dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/latitudePonto"
    android:layout_width="67dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/longitudePonto"
    android:layout_width="67dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text=""/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Gabriel,

Revisei seu código e não encontrei nada muito óbvio de erro. Então, vou sugerir para você testar algumas coisas:

1) O json está vindo corretamente ? Na classe HttpHandler coloca um Log.d da resposta antes de dar o return para ter certeza que o json está correto.

2) Você está rodando o AsyncTask de dentro do onCreate (main thread), o que não é recomendado.
Tenta assim:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new GetPontos().execute();
    }
}.start();
```

Sobre isso tem uma pergunta semelhante no link abaixo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874990/async-task-android-execute

Comment: Tentei fazer o que me disse, mas continua vindo nulo, porem não sei o motivo de continuar nulo a resposta do meu arquivo Json..

Comment: Deve ser o teu método convertStreamToString(is) ... coloca o source dele aqui pra eu ver ...